# Casting double pointers of base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an Abstract class, say `Animal`.  From this class, I have many inheriting classes, such as `Cat`, `Dog`, `Mouse`.  I have a method that I want to be able to take pointers to pointers of these objects.  So `void someMethod(Animal **anAnimal);`

How is this accomplished?  It seems I am not able to cast upwards like this.  I am trying the following:

```
Dog *d = new Dog(x); //some parameter x.
Animal **animal = &d;
someMethod(animal);

//where someMethod has the method signature...
void someMethod(Animal **anAnimal);
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I accomplish what I'm attempting?

Comment: Aside from the pointer question, why would you want double pointers? The only good application of double pointers that I know of, is when you want to modify where an incoming pointer points to. But in C++, that is better done with a reference: `void someMethod(Animal*& anAnimal)` now takes a reference to a pointer, and is able to modify the passed in pointer, without the double pointers needed.

Comment: Why is this better than a double pointer?? Passing non-const references arguments is generally decouraged. Dereferencing the double pointer makes it straightforward that you are modifying some external pointer, while in your case it's not. And from a compiler point of view, both are generally identical regarding generated code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need an `Animal*`:

```
Dog* d = new Dog(x);
Animal* a = d;
Animal** animal = &a;
someMethod(animal);
```

An `Animal**` can only point to an `Animal*`.  It would be very bad if it could point to a `Dog*`.  If it could, you could do something like this:

```
Dog* d = new Dog(x);
Animal** animal = &d;
*animal = new Hippopotamus();
```

Now `d` points to a `Hippopotamus`, which is very wrong indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a temporary of type `Animal*`:

```
Dog *d = new Dog(x); //some parameter x.
Animal *a = d;
Animal **animal = &a;
someMethod(animal);
```

The reason for this is that &d is `Dog**`, which cannot be converted to `Animal**` even if `Dog*` can be converted to `Animal*`.

Normally you 'd fix this inline using something like this (*warning -- does not compile!*):

```
Dog *d = new Dog(x); //some parameter x.
Animal **animal = &(static_cast<Animal*>(d));
someMethod(animal);
```

However, this is not possible because the return value of `static_cast` is a temporary (technically, its a `rvalue`) so you cannot get its address. Therefore, you need the extra `Animal*` local to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Going to have to do a cast.

```
Animal **animal = (Animal **)&d;
```

Comment: Not sure why I was dinged; can someone provide some input as to why this is a bad implementation?  It compiles and works properly in GCC (g++).

Comment: `class Animal {} ; class Graphic {}; class Dog : public Graphic, public Animal {}; Dog *pDog = 0;  Animal *pAnimal = pDog; /* This compiles, and the code is correct.  pAnimal points to the Animal part of pDog. */ Animal **ppAnimal = (Animal **)&pDog;  /* This compiles, but the code is broken.  *ppAnimal may point to the Graphic part of pDog, depending on the compiler implementation.  */`