# Cast DirectX interfaces to IUnknown pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, com, directx, iunknown

Having quite a few interfaces in my code, I wanted to encapsulate repeating `Release` code in another method and not in a macro because this is C++ and I hate using macros. My initial attempt was to write a method such as

```
void SafeRelease(IUnknown **ppInterface) {
    if(*ppInterface) {
        (*ppInterface)->Release();
        (*ppInterface) = nullptr;
    }
}
```

however applying this method to a `IDirect3DSurface9 *` e.g. like `SafeRelease(&mySurface)` yields the error `IDirect3DSurface9 **` is incompatible with `IUnknown **`.

1. What am I doing here wrong?
2. Is there a better approach (hopefully not using macros) to implement such a function?

Comment: Is there a reason for creating such a function as opposed to using `ComPtr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my method:

```
template <typename T> void SafeRelease(T*& ptr)
{
    if(ptr)
    {
        ptr->Release();
        ptr = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
IDirect3DDevice9 *pD3DDevice = NULL;
d3d->CreateDevice(..., &pD3DDevice);
SafeRelease(pD3DDevice);
```

You may `inline` this function if you want.

Comment: +1. Your template with the `*&` is more convenient than my initial attempt and metal's suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template:

```
template<class DXInterface>
void SafeRelease(DXInterface **ppInterface) {
    if(*ppInterface) {
        (*ppInterface)->Release();
        (*ppInterface) = nullptr;
    }
}
```

You could also use a std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr to automatically cleanup:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Releaser {
   template<class DXInterface>
   void operator()(DXInterface *pInterface) const {
       if(pInterface) {
           pInterface->Release();
       }
   }
};

// For illustrative purposes only (supplied in DX9 headers)
struct IDirect3DSurface9 { void Release() { std::cout << "Released surface\n";} };
struct IDirect3DTexture9 { void Release() { std::cout << "Released texture\n";} };

void DX9CreateSurface( IDirect3DSurface9** surface ) 
{ 
    *surface = new IDirect3DSurface9();
}

void DX9CreateTexture( IDirect3DTexture9** texture ) 
{ 
    *texture = new IDirect3DTexture9();
}

// Your factory functions
IDirect3DSurface9* createSurface( /*init params go here*/ )
{
    IDirect3DSurface9* surface;
    DX9CreateSurface( &surface );
    return surface;
}

IDirect3DTexture9* createTexture( /*init params go here*/ )
{
    IDirect3DTexture9* texture;
    DX9CreateTexture( &texture );
    return texture;
}

int main()
{
  typedef std::unique_ptr<IDirect3DSurface9, Releaser> SurfacePtr;
  typedef std::unique_ptr<IDirect3DTexture9, Releaser> TexturePtr;

  SurfacePtr surface( createSurface() );
  TexturePtr texture( createTexture() );
  // ... use surface and texture here
  // Automatically released here when their lifetimes ends.
}
```

Note that they use the same Releaser, and note that a call to surface.reset() would also release the interface and would set the pointer inside the unique_ptr to null to boot. These two objects could be members of your class rather than objects in main().

Comment: This way I would have to define this method for all the Direct3D interfaces I am using and which need to be released. This is the reason why I wanted to use `IUnknown`.

Comment: Better to make Releaser's operator() a template.

Comment: Technically, the compiler would define them all for you, and it would almost certainly inline that function anyway, regardless of whether you make it a template. See also my update about using smart pointers.

Comment: I am currently not using smart pointers and doing this therefore the old fashioned way. To create such an interface I rely on functions like `CreateOffscreenPlainSurface` which take a `IDirect3DSurface9 **` parameter marked as `_Out_`. How can I let the function access my smart pointer then, because it surely won't work just by passing a `unique_ptr<IDirect3DSurface9>`, will it?

Comment: If it's taking a double pointer in, then you would need to use a separate object (or your own little factory function) and then hand that over to the smart pointer to manage. If it's only using a single pointer, then you can call unique_ptr::get().

Comment: This whole workaround with factories and smart pointers is too much - I will stick with the template which actually works now.

Comment: As you wish. I added some factories to illustrate. Using smart pointers virtually eliminates resource leaks, which can build up over time if you do a lot of creating resources, as in a game.

Comment: For your interest, the way Flávio Toribio has written his template seems much better with a `*&` rather than `**` as I do not have to reference the pointers once more!

Comment: My Releaser functor also does not have a double pointer *and* it supports RAII. Why program in C-style, especially when the C++ version is safer in the face of bugs and exceptions, easier to read and reason about, and free of run-time penalties with inlining enabled? Worry more about the game and less about the plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing here wrong?

I just had the same question, also for COM `SafeRelease`. So here goes:

```
void SafeRelease(IUnknown **ppInterface) 
...
IDirect3DSurface9 * mySurface = new ...
...
SafeRelease(&mySurface);
```

`IDirect3DSurface9 *`, by virtue of inheritance, can be cast to `IUnknown *`.
But, counterintuitively, `IDirect3DSurface9 **` cannot be cast to `IUnknown **`.
If it were allowed, then inside your `SafeRelease(IUnknown**)` you could do the following:

```
// obtain a pointer to an instance of some random subinterface of IUnknown
*ppInterface = pMyRamdomComInterfacePointer;
```

And thus we would have stored a pointer to some random `IUnknown` derivative in a pointer to `IDirect3DSurface9`. That would violate the C++ type system. Which is why casting any other type but `T**` to `T**` is not allowed. In other words, a variable of type `T**` can only be assigned a `ppT` (a value of type `T**`) and not a `ppSomeSubytpeOfT`.

Compare this one: [How come a pointer to a derived class cannot be passed to a function expecting a reference to a pointer to the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7186341/269126) And this one: [Casting double pointers of base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5446767/269126).

For COM `SafeRelease`, either a template (as suggested here) or a macro will do.