# Qt: QWidgets and Pointers

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, null

I currently have 3 classes that are public QWidgets.
-> x, y ,z are all qwidgets.

In my mainwindow I have pointers to x, y, z.

So the members:

```
X* m_x;
Y* m_y;
Z* m_z;
```

A member function:

```
void MainWindow::deleteScreen(QWidget** widget)
{
    if(widget != NULL)
    {
        delete widget;
        widget = NULL;
    }
}
```

called as: 
`deleteScreen(&m_x);` -> causes invalid conversion.

If I changed the `deleteScreen` param to `QWidget* widget` and call as `deleteScreen(m_x)` it will delete the memory but it won't set `m_x` to NULL. (only the local variable, widget)

-> Is there any way to make the `deleteScreen` function delete the given widget AND put the value of the member variable on NULL?

Thank you!

Comment: if ( widget != null  &&  *widget != null ) {`delete *widget; *widget = NULL;}`

Comment: Are you sure that QWidgets must be deleted? AFAIK, Qt implements some kind of garbage collection.

Comment: @AlexFarber I did not know that Qt had garbage collection. But if it didn't how would your solution work? I tried something like that but I can't call the function with deleteScreen(&m_x) -> invalid conversion.

Comment: Qt does not have garbage collection but QObject is an implementation of the Composite Pattern so all child objects are deleted when the parent is deleted.

Comment: May I add the comment, that it is not necessary to test for a NULL pointer before deleting it? Deleting a NULL pointer is actually well defined, and does.... nothing. So drop the if(widget != NULL). It is superfluous and makes your code look less professional. ;-)

Comment: If you really want to 'delete' it and assign a NULL value, why not use reference. void MainWindow::deleteScreen(QWidget* & widget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, [a double pointer to a base class cannot be used as a double pointer to a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446767/casting-double-pointers-of-base-classes); so you probably have to resort to templates:

```
template<typename T>
void deleteAndCleanup(T*& ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
}

// called like this:
deleteAndCleanup(m_x);
```

Comment: You don't need to check for NULL in the version that takes a reference. Calling delete on a NULL pointer is perfectly fine. (You still need to check for NULL in the version that takes a pointer of course, since it gets dereferenced.)

Comment: @NikosC.: the NULL check isn't needed in any of them; if the double-pointer is NULL there's a serious logic flaw in the caller, so a segfault is much deserved.

Comment: Hey, I tried the first solution but that gives me the invalid conversion:
error: invalid conversion from 'X**' to 'QWidget**' [-fpermissive]

Comment: The second solution also gives an error:
 error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::deleteScreen(X*&)'

Comment: @secondVISION: the second solution gives you that error because you haven't updated the declaration inside the `class` block, but it suffers the same problems as the first one (you can't use a reference to a pointer to a base class to pass a pointer to a derived class); see updated answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Alright, thank you! The new solution works. I'll read that other question for some information.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not so much that you want to delete the QWidgets but that you are using the pointers to them to determine whether they have been deleted or not.

Qt has a solution for this. For `QObject` classes, you can use the `QPointer` class as a guard. It is aware of whether the `QObject` it contains has been deleted or not by being connected internally to the object's deletion.

Try the following as an alternate to your code:

```
QPointer<X> m_x;
QPointer<Y> m_y;
QPointer<Z> m_z;


template<typename T>
void MainWindow::deleteScreen(QPointer<T> &widget)
{
    if(!widget.isNull() && qobject_cast<QWidget>(widget) != 0)
    {
        widget->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `&& qobject_cast<QWidget>(widget) != 0` part is not really useful alone. If you want to keep it, you should probably add `&& widget->parent() == this` or something, to make it actually work as some kind of safety check.

Comment: The reason I put that check in was merely to make the functionality similar to secondVISION's original code, that only `QWidget` items should be handled by the function. This restriction is lost by making it a template function since `QPointer` can hold any `QObject`, not only `QWidget`s